# How to get visa to stay longer in US?

Tags: visas, usa, uk-citizens

We have a Florida property and want to spend 4 months there in order to miss the cold British winters. Is it easy to get a visa for this?

Comment: Usually (at least for most of South American countries is) you can visit USA (with tourism visa) for 3 month maximum (continuously). But you can get an extension (3 months more) in your embassy, once you are close to the first 3 months.

Comment: https://uk.usembassy.gov/visas/tourism-visitor/

Answer (score 5):

As a British citizen, you can spend up to 90 days per visit on the visa waiver program (VWP).  Once you have entered the US under the VWP, there is effectively no way to extend your visit.  (The exceptions are for close family members of US citizens and for things like medical emergencies.)

In order to spend more than 90 days in the US, you can apply *before you travel* for a B-2 visa.  B-2 visitors are generally admitted for six months per visit.

More information is available on the [Tourism and Visitor pages](https://uk.usembassy.gov/visas/tourism-visitor/) of the US diplomatic mission to the UK.

You ask

> Is it easy to get a visa for this?

For some people, it is quite easy, and for others, it is quite difficult.  Most British citizens who can afford to own property in Florida will probably not have much trouble with it, but there are all sorts of factors that could make it very difficult indeed.